# Number of stores where a product is sold MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a SSRS dataset filtered by date with the following structure :

```
   ProductId QuantitySold 
       1           24
       2           47
       3           34
      ...         ...
```

I can't figure out how to add a calculated measure to provide the number of stores where the products are sold. I have a group measure named sales associated with multiple dimensions (Products, Stores, Time..) and the measure QuantitySold.

I tried distinctcount of Stores attribute but the dataset won't execute.

The desired results should be similar to this :

```
   ProductId  QuantitySold NumberOfStores
       1           24           3
       2           47           12
       3           34           2
```

FactSales Has the following attributes :

```
StoreId ProductId DateId Quantity Total
```

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: be better if we have a bit more detail please - either SSRS expressions you've tried, or MDX solutions you've tried which are not working

Comment: I tried the following calculated member : `DISTINCTCOUNT([DimStore].[Store].members)`

Comment: Add a measure with the DistinctCount aggregation based on the FactSales table. See my blog for examples: http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/the-best-distinctcount-practice-in-ssas.html